# How to make Minitest run faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

In a new Rails project, Minitest is running very slow:

First I set Spring binstubs:

```
david$ bundle exec spring binstub --all
* bin/rake: spring inserted
* bin/rails: spring inserted
```

Next I run the default test (navigation_test.rb) through Spring:

```
david$ time bundle exec spring rake test
Run options: --seed 32313

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.003368s, 296.9121 runs/s, 296.9121 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

real    0m5.171s
user    0m0.581s
sys     0m0.098s
```

The next runs are slightly faster, but still very slow (around 3 secs):

```
david$ time bundle exec spring rake test
Run options: --seed 48522

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.003506s, 285.2253 runs/s, 285.2253 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

real    0m3.159s
user    0m0.579s
sys     0m0.088s
```

If I run it again without bundler, it's a little faster:

```
david$ time spring rake test
Run options: --seed 55025

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.003413s, 292.9974 runs/s, 292.9974 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

real    0m2.677s
user    0m0.087s
sys     0m0.032s
```

Anyone using Minitest+Spring? How to make it run faster?

Using Rails 4.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have set up spring and binstubs, there is no reason to continue to call bundler. Try this:

```
$ time bin/rake test
```

Comment: Ok, that works well in a normal app. I thought it was the same for an engine (I was trying it with an engine), but the engine is way slower. I have open another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448243/how-to-make-minitest-run-faster-in-a-rails-engine